# SonarQube 5.0.1 won't start

Tags: sonarqube

System is a Linux-x86-64. We have SonarQube 4.0 running but can't run any version above that. We've been trying to get 5.0.1 up and running but it stops after about two seconds.

We see this error on the log but are not sure if it's normal:

```
Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries do not exist.
    Loading native library failed: libwrapper-linux-x86-64.so  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-linux-x86-64 in java.library.path
    Loaded native library: libwrapper.so
```

Here is the log:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./sonar.sh status
+ DEF_APP_NAME=SonarQube
+ DEF_APP_LONG_NAME=SonarQube
+ SONAR_HOME=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1
+ PLATFORM=linux-x86-64
+ APP_NAME=SonarQube
+ APP_LONG_NAME=SonarQube
+ WRAPPER_CMD=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1/bin/linux-x86-64/wrapper
+ WRAPPER_CONF=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1/conf/wrapper.conf
+ PRIORITY=
+ PIDDIR=/var/run/sonar
+ case $0 in
++ pwd
+ PWD=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1/bin/linux-x86-64
+ SCRIPT=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./sonar.sh
+ CHANGED=true
+ '[' Xtrue '!=' X ']'
++ echo /usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./sonar.sh
++ sed -e 's; ;:;g'
+ SAFESCRIPT=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./sonar.sh
++ echo /usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1/bin/linux-x86-64/./sonar.sh
++ sed -e 's;/; ;g'
+ TOKENS=' usr local sonarqube-5.0.1 bin linux-x86-64 . sonar.sh'
+ REALPATH=
+ for C in '$TOKENS'
++ echo usr
++ sed -e 's;:; ;g'
+ C=usr
+ REALPATH=/usr
+ '[' -h /usr ']'
+ for C in '$TOKENS'
++ echo local
++ sed -e 's;:; ;g'
+ C=local
+ REALPATH=/usr/local
+ '[' -h /usr/local ']'
+ for C in '$TOKENS'
++ echo sonarqube-5.0.1
++ sed -e 's;:; ;g'
+ C=sonarqube-5.0.1
+ REALPATH=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1
+ '[' -h /usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1 ']'
+ for C in '$TOKENS'
++ echo bin
++ sed -e 's;:; ;g'
+ C=bin
+ REALPATH=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1/bin
+ '[' -h /usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1/bin ']'
+ for C in '$TOKENS'
++ echo linux-x86-64
++ sed -e 's;:; ;g'
+ C=linux-x86-64
+ REALPATH=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1/bin/linux-x86-64
+ '[' -h /usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1/bin/linux-x86-64 ']'
+ for C in '$TOKENS'
++ echo .
++ sed -e 's;:; ;g'
+ C=.
+ REALPATH=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1/bin/linux-x86-64/.
+ '[' -h /usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1/bin/linux-x86-64/. ']'
+ for C in '$TOKENS'
++ echo sonar.sh
send a packet START : start
Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
calling WrapperListener.start()
Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook started
WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
read a packet STOP : 0
JVM requested a shutdown. (0)
wrapperStopProcess(0) called.
Sending stop signal to JVM
send a packet STOP : NULL
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
Thread, Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook, handling the shutdown process.
shutdownJVM(0) Thread:Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOPPED : 0
read a packet STOPPED : 0
JVM signalled that it was stopped.
Closing socket.
socket read no code (closed?).
server listening on port 32001.
JVM exited normally.
Signal trapped.  Details:
  signal number=17 (SIGCHLD), source="unknown"
Received SIGCHLD, checking JVM process status.
JVM process exited with a code of 0, leaving the wrapper exit code set to 0.
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook complete
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
Spawning intermediate process...
Spawning daemon process...
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Using tick timer.
server listening on port 32000.
Command[0] : /auto/uscmweb/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java
Command[1] : -Djava.awt.headless=true
Command[2] : -Xms256m
Command[3] : -Xmx512m
Command[4] : -Djava.library.path=./lib
Command[5] : -classpath
Command[7] : -Dwrapper.key=0bS89TdW9DaXfF5z
Command[8] : -Dwrapper.port=32000
Command[9] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000
Command[10] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999
Command[11] : -Dwrapper.debug=TRUE
Command[12] : -Dwrapper.pid=9207
Command[13] : -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
Command[14] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper
Command[15] : -Dwrapper.service=TRUE
Command[16] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10
Command[17] : -Dwrapper.jvmid=1
Command[18] : org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
Command[19] : org.sonar.application.App
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
send a packet START : start
Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
calling WrapperListener.start()
Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook started
WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
read a packet STOP : 0
JVM requested a shutdown. (0)
wrapperStopProcess(0) called.
Sending stop signal to JVM
send a packet STOP : NULL
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
Thread, Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook, handling the shutdown process.
shutdownJVM(0) Thread:Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOPPED : 0
read a packet STOPPED : 0
JVM signalled that it was stopped.
Closing socket.
socket read no code (closed?).
server listening on port 32001.
JVM exited normally.
Signal trapped.  Details:
  signal number=17 (SIGCHLD), source="unknown"
Received SIGCHLD, checking JVM process status.
JVM process exited with a code of 0, leaving the wrapper exit code set to 0.
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook complete
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
Spawning intermediate process...
Spawning daemon process...
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Using tick timer.
server listening on port 32000.
Command[0] : /auto/uscmweb/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java
Command[1] : -Djava.awt.headless=true
Command[2] : -Xms256m
Command[3] : -Xmx512m
Command[4] : -Djava.library.path=./lib
Command[5] : -classpath
Command[7] : -Dwrapper.key=0bS89TdW9DaXfF5z
Command[8] : -Dwrapper.port=32000
Command[9] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000
Command[10] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999
Command[11] : -Dwrapper.debug=TRUE
Command[12] : -Dwrapper.pid=9207
Command[13] : -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
Command[14] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper
Command[15] : -Dwrapper.service=TRUE
Command[16] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10
Command[17] : -Dwrapper.jvmid=1
Command[18] : org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
Command[19] : org.sonar.application.App
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Wrapper Manager: JVM #1
Running a 64-bit JVM.
Wrapper Manager: Registering shutdown hook
Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper
Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific librari
es do not exist.
Loading native library failed: libwrapper-linux-x86-64.so  Cause: java.lang.Unsa
tisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-linux-x86-64 in java.library.path
Loaded native library: libwrapper.so
Calling native initialization method.
Inside native WrapperManager initialization method
Java Version   : 1.8.0_40-b25 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation

Control event monitor thread started.
Startup runner thread started.
WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@4a574795, args[
]) called by thread: main
Communications runner thread started.
Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
Failed attempt to bind using local port 31000
Opened Socket from 31001 to 32000
Send a packet KEY : 0bS89TdW9DaXfF5z
handleSocket(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=32000,localport=31001])
accepted a socket from 127.0.0.1 on port 31001
read a packet KEY : 0bS89TdW9DaXfF5z
Got key from JVM: 0bS89TdW9DaXfF5z
send a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
send a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
send a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Start Application.
send a packet START : start
Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
Received a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
PingTimeout from Wrapper is 0
Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
Received a packet START : start
calling WrapperListener.start()
Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to c
omplete.
WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook started
WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOP : 0
read a packet STOP : 0
JVM requested a shutdown. (0)
wrapperStopProcess(0) called.
Sending stop signal to JVM
send a packet STOP : NULL
Startup runner thread stopped.
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
Thread, Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook, handling the shutdown process.
shutdownJVM(0) Thread:Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
Send a packet STOPPED : 0
read a packet STOPPED : 0
JVM signalled that it was stopped.
Closing socket.
socket read no code (closed?).
server listening on port 32001.
JVM exited normally.
Signal trapped.  Details:
  signal number=17 (SIGCHLD), source="unknown"
Received SIGCHLD, checking JVM process status.
JVM process exited with a code of 0, leaving the wrapper exit code set to 0.
Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook complete
Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=false, exitCode=null
WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: If you try to start a fresh SonarQube install without modifying *anything* on the configuration files, does it work? A couple of guys here at SonarSource are working on 64 bits Fedora or Ubuntu, and they don't have any problem.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this. The fix was to make sure that all of the files in the directory are owned by the user you are logged in as.

```
chown -R sonaruser /usr/local/sonarqube-5.0.1
chown sonaruser /etc/init.d/sonar
```

Comment: I am facing the similar issue in starting the sonarqube 5.0.1


Launching a JVM...
Unable to start JVM: No such file or directory (2)
Signal trapped.  Details:
  signal number=17 (SIGCHLD), source="unknown"
Received SIGCHLD, checking JVM process status.
JVM process exited with a code of 1, setting the wrapper exit code to 1.
JVM exited while loading the application.
JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.

User permissions are root and I am starting the sonarqube as a root user.

Comment: @kevcodez Yes. Pls refer to my answer on my another post- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355815/error-in-sonar-startup-unable-to-start-jvm-no-such-file-or-directory-2