# Sonarqube server wont start on linux

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I tried to setup sonarqube server when I tried to start it started but within few seconds it stopped. Here are the details :

Linux version:
Enterprise Linux Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 (Carthage)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 (Tikanga)

Console Log :

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Using tick timer.
wrapperp | server listening on port 32000.
wrapper  | Command[0] : /utilsoftware/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/java
wrapper  | Command[1] : -Djava.awt.headless=true
wrapper  | Command[2] : -Xms3m
wrapper  | Command[3] : -Xmx32m
wrapper  | Command[4] : -Djava.library.path=./lib
wrapper  | Command[5] : -classpath
wrapper  | Command[6] : ../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:../../lib/sonar-application-5.1.jar
wrapper  | Command[7] : -Dwrapper.key=SDS6vyrZA_ppWkqC
wrapper  | Command[8] : -Dwrapper.port=32000
wrapper  | Command[9] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000
wrapper  | Command[10] : -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999
wrapper  | Command[11] : -Dwrapper.debug=TRUE
wrapper  | Command[12] : -Dwrapper.pid=14823
wrapper  | Command[13] : -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3
wrapper  | Command[14] : -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper
wrapper  | Command[15] : -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10
wrapper  | Command[16] : -Dwrapper.jvmid=1
wrapper  | Command[17] : org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper  | Command[18] : org.sonar.application.App
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main  Using classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6e3e48f2
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: JVM #1
jvm 1    | Running a 64-bit JVM.
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: Registering shutdown hook
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper
jvm 1    | Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries do not exist.
jvm 1    | Loading native library failed: libwrapper-linux-x86-64.so  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-linux-x86-64 in java.library.path
jvm 1    | Loaded native library: libwrapper.so
jvm 1    | Calling native initialization method.
jvm 1    | Inside native WrapperManager initialization method
jvm 1    | Java Version   : 1.7.0_75-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
jvm 1    | Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | Control event monitor thread started.
jvm 1    | Startup runner thread started.
jvm 1    | WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@6fe84244, args[]) called by thread: main
jvm 1    | Communications runner thread started.
jvm 1    | Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
jvm 1    | Opened Socket from 31000 to 32000
jvm 1    | Send a packet KEY : SDS6vyrZA_ppWkqC
jvm 1    | handleSocket(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=32000,localport=31000])
wrapperp | accepted a socket from 127.0.0.1 on port 31000
wrapperp | read a packet KEY : SDS6vyrZA_ppWkqC
wrapper  | Got key from JVM: SDS6vyrZA_ppWkqC
wrapperp | send a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
wrapperp | send a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
wrapperp | send a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
wrapper  | Start Application.
wrapperp | send a packet START : start
jvm 1    | Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
jvm 1    | Received a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 0
jvm 1    | PingTimeout from Wrapper is 0
jvm 1    | Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
jvm 1    | Received a packet START : start
jvm 1    | calling WrapperListener.start()
jvm 1    | Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
jvm 1    | WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
jvm 1    | 2015.04.09 15:28:43 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /utilsoftware/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/utilsoftware/sonarqube-5.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process6171890893544068550properties
jvm 1    | Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
wrapperp | read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
wrapper  | JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
jvm 1    | Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=false, exitCode=null
jvm 1    | WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
jvm 1    | returned from WrapperListener.start()
jvm 1    | Send a packet STARTED : 
jvm 1    | Startup runner thread stopped.
wrapperp | read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
wrapper  | JVM signalled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
wrapperp | read a packet STARTED : 
wrapper  | JVM signalled that it was started.
wrapperp | send a packet PING : ping
jvm 1    | Received a packet PING : ping
jvm 1    | Send a packet PING : ok
wrapperp | read a packet PING : ok
wrapper  | Got ping response from JVM
jvm 1    | 2015.04.09 15:28:50 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
jvm 1    | 2015.04.09 15:28:50 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /utilsoftware/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -server -Djava.io.tmpdir=/utilsoftware/sonarqube-5.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/utilsoftware/sonarqube-5.1/extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/ojdbc6.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /tmp/sq-process4681369525824251964properties
wrapperp | send a packet PING : ping
jvm 1    | Received a packet PING : ping
jvm 1    | Send a packet PING : ok
wrapperp | read a packet PING : ok
wrapper  | Got ping response from JVM
wrapperp | send a packet PING : ping
jvm 1    | Received a packet PING : ping
jvm 1    | Send a packet PING : ok
wrapperp | read a packet PING : ok
wrapper  | Got ping response from JVM
wrapperp | send a packet PING : ping
jvm 1    | Received a packet PING : ping
jvm 1    | Send a packet PING : ok
wrapperp | read a packet PING : ok
wrapper  | Got ping response from JVM
jvm 1    | 2015.04.09 15:29:01 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopping
jvm 1    | 2015.04.09 15:29:02 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopped
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook started
jvm 1    | WrapperManager.stop(0) called by thread: Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
jvm 1    | Send a packet STOP : 0
wrapperp | read a packet STOP : 0
wrapper  | JVM requested a shutdown. (0)
wrapper  | wrapperStopProcess(0) called.
wrapper  | Sending stop signal to JVM
wrapperp | send a packet STOP : NULL
jvm 1    | Received a packet STOP : 
jvm 1    | Thread, Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook, handling the shutdown process.
jvm 1    | calling listener.stop()
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: stop(0)
jvm 1    | returned from listener.stop() -> 0
jvm 1    | shutdownJVM(0) Thread:Wrapper-Shutdown-Hook
jvm 1    | Send a packet STOPPED : 0
wrapperp | read a packet STOPPED : 0
wrapper  | JVM signalled that it was stopped.
jvm 1    | Closing socket.
wrapperp | socket read no code (closed?).
wrapperp | server listening on port 32001.
wrapper  | JVM exited normally.
wrapper  | Signal trapped.  Details:
wrapper  |   signal number=17 (SIGCHLD), source="unknown"
wrapper  | Received SIGCHLD, checking JVM process status.
wrapper  | JVM process exited with a code of 0, leaving the wrapper exit code set to 0.
jvm 1    | Wrapper Manager: ShutdownHook complete
jvm 1    | Server daemon shut down
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I was not able to find any other details. Can someone help me out here.

Comment: Do you have any log in ``${SQ_HOME}/logs/sonar.log``? It seems that the embedded ElasticSearch server starts, but not the Web application server.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. You might want to check the path to jdk bin in /conf/wrapper.conf file. Pls refer to this for details - [Error in sonar startup, Unable to start JVM: No such file or directory (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355815/error-in-sonar-startup-unable-to-start-jvm-no-such-file-or-directory-2)

Answer (score 0):

please clean the web folder and restart your server from sonar/bin/linux-version/sonar.sh restart/start/stop.

if this also not solves the problem.check with sonarQube configuration and database credentials.